# User is being redirected by SSO during OAuth 2.0 authorization dance

Tags: oauth2, single-sign-on

I'm building an app that requires users to authenticate with Salesforce.  This is done with using a connected app and sends users through the Oauth redirect dance, as described here: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com.

The problem I'm encountering occurs with an SSO implementation that steps in to authenticate the user automatically.  The user is authenticated and redirected back to the authorization server, but once authorized, is redirected to the Salesforce home page, rather than the Oauth callback redirect as configured in the connected app (and passed as query param).

This is happening between steps 3 and 4 on this diagram: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/File:OAuthWebServerFlow.png

Question:
Is there a way I can force a request to:
https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?...
which redirects to:
https://na[XX].salesforce.com/setup/secur/RemoteAccessAuthorizationPage.apexp?source=...
to load that page without triggering SSO to automatically authenticate the user?

Example: My app is trying to implement the same flow that one would see on Workbench or Dataloader.io.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Double check that you're using the login server URL rather than the Salesforce instance URL